# KoolReport shows blank page in laravel vuejs

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to use the KoolReport in laravel vuejs but it shows me the blank page any help will be highly appreciated.

**Code in MyReport.php is like below**

```
<?php
namespace App\Reports;

class MyReport extends \koolreport\KoolReport
{
    //We leave this blank to demo only
```

**Code in MyReport.view.php is like below**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>It works</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code in ReportController.php is like below**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Reports\MyReport;

class ReportController extends Controller
{
    public function __contruct()
    {
        $this->middleware("guest");
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $report = new MyReport;
        $report->run();
        return view("report",["report"=>$report]);
    }
}
```

**Code in report.blade.php is like below**

```
{{ $report->render() }}
```

**Code in ReportController@index is like below**

```
Route::get('/report', "ReportController@index");
```